# JRuby mysterious stack trace

Tags: ruby, jruby, stack-trace

I'm using JRuby 1.4.0 complete jar in one of my projects. I'm executing it from ant via the exec task:

```
java -jar jruby1.4.0.jar script.rb script_params
```

The thing is, on some computers I receive this:

```
[exec] Exception in thread "main" :1: no !/ in spec (IOError)
[exec]    ...internal jruby stack elided...
[exec]    from (unknown).(unknown)(:1)
```

Has anyone encountered it before? What can I do to get a more informative stack trace?

Comment: Can you show the top few lines of your script?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run with -d command line switch and see if you get a more informative exception:

```
java -jar jruby1.4.0.jar -d script.rb script_params
```

Comment: Thanks. You're the one that also replied on the mailing list, right? I asked here before I asked there.